# Как выглядит таблица маршрутизации для хоста и маршрутизатора?

Tags: сеть, подсети

Как выглядит таблица маршрутизации для хоста и маршрутизатора ?  Например для такой сети

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для хоста как я понимаю кроме маршрута по умолчанию и localhost никаких других записей в общем случае не будет, а вот для маршрутизатора R1, который расположен внутри сети, я не совсем понимаю какие записи стоят в полях адреса следующего шлюза

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А попытайтесь решить эту задачку сами - тут же просто...

Comment: @eri, я тёмен: какой практический смысл имеет запись 0.0.0.0/32 ?

Comment: В качесвте адресов шлюза в локальной сети будут адреса интрефейсов для этой локальной сети, то есть для 192.168.0.35 и 192.168.25 - это 192.168.0.1 ???

Comment: @ЕгорСергеев анричбл же

Comment: анричбл ??? не понимаю таких слов)

Comment: @eri я правильно подумал ?

Comment: @ЕгорСергеев не туда ответил. Это к предыдущему коммента

Comment: @ЕгорСергеев да, тут только нолики коварны

Comment: @eri   У маршрутизатора может быть маршрут по умолчанию ?

Comment: @ЕгорСергеев может, но на схеме его нет

Comment: @eri На схеме интрефейсы и ip как я понимаю, под маршрут по умолчанию не нужен отдельный интерфейс, что должно быть на схеме ?

Comment: Под маршрут по умолчанию рисуется линия до облачка

Comment: Маршрут по умолчанию не обязательно до облачка. Если вы 2 компьютера между собой соединяете, вы в маршрутах по умолчанию, на каждом компьютере, указываете ip адрес другого компьютера

Answer (score 0):

```
192.168.0.35
192.168.0.25
188.243.184.210    eth0 : 188.243.184.209
```

Ну вроде так.
0.0.0.0 это типо адрес интернета, ну или маршрут по умолчанию, но там обычно и маска 0.0.0.0